# Book recommendation for introductory percolation theory

Tags: measure-theory, book-recommendation, percolation

I want some recommendation on introductory level books on the mentioned topics. if someone recommend good lecture notes/tutorials on the mentioned topic that also appreciable. If someone share some beginner level interesting research work on this topics that also helpful.

I personally didn't find any suggested book on this topic on the math stack exchange. So I'm asking this.

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/percolation/75F54872F9FE1DFDB2EE95B37E0BC382

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I think the best intro to percolation by far is the following set of lecture notes by Hugo Duminil- Copin:

[https://www.ihes.fr/~duminil/publi/2017percolation.pdf](https://www.ihes.fr/%7Eduminil/publi/2017percolation.pdf)

It comes with some really nice exercises and covers quite a lot in just 30 pages.

Answer (score 1):

Either of these two books from Geoffrey Grimmett should fit the bill.

1. Percolation.
2. Probability on Graphs.

In particular, I found that working through 2 was easier. There is also a draft on [his website](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Egrg/books/pgs.html). Note that this only covers the case of percolation on graphs. There is also the study of percolation on $\mathbb{R}$, known as continuum percolation, which is not covered.